# Collection method not available for mongodb Node.js driver version

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code:

```
 import {Collection, MongoClient, ServerOptions} from 'mongodb';

 MongoClient.connect(this.uri).then(function (client) {
      const db = client.db('local');
      const coll = db.collection('oplog.rs');
      const q = coll.find({}, {ts: 1})
         .sort({$natural: -1})
         .limit(1)
         .nextObject();
  });
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: coll.find(...).sort(...).limit(...).nextObject is not a
>   function

I am on  `"mongodb": "^3.0.4",`

Does anyone know a workaround for this? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

`nextObject` is not a function for MongoDB, try with `next()` or `next(function(err, yourObject) {})` instead